# Running Julia and getting colors to output on (unix-like) command line

Tags: terminal, colors, julia, xfce

I am getting started with Julia, and am watching this [video](https://youtu.be/4igzy3bGVkQ?t=2403), and at the time I linked to, the presenter runs the command

```
palette = distinguishable_colors(100)
```

Now if I run that in my terminal (xfce4-terminal), I just get output that looks

```
 RGB{N0f8}(0.471,0.482,0.231)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.714,0.976,0.851)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.855,0.0,0.247)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.18,0.129,0.141)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.345,0.082)
 RGB{N0f8}(1.0,0.557,0.114)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.4,0.455,0.694)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.804,0.678)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.0,0.498,0.388)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.6,0.435,0.239)
```

Is there a way to get it to output actually colors on the terminal (like in the video)?  Is this something that has to be updated in a separate config (and what exactly?), or something that needs to be tuned in Julia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can just use the Crayons package.
This package is using `Int`s for representation of colors and the API of `Colors.jl` is rather verbose here (unless you want directly access `pallette` object fields which would be not elegant).

```
using Color, Crayons

palette = distinguishable_colors(8);

crs = [Crayon(foreground = reinterpret.((red(palette[i]), green(palette[i]),blue(palette[i]))) ) for i in 1:8];

println.(crs, string.("This is line ",1:8));
```

[image]

Note that the first line ha black color so it is not visible, however you can always add something like `background=:white` to the `Crayon` constructor.

[image]